# Magmi import error

Tags: magmi

trying out the Magmi importer. Saved a file under the /var/import directory, which is found by Magmi and displayed in the dropdown of the file to import section, but when I run the import process I get the error message "NO FILE".

Answer (score 1):

Check the file permission using for the file using linux console command **chmod** or cPanel

> [magmi_root]/magmi/conf/Magmi_CSVDataSource.conf

If the file is not writable, Magmi cannot save the settings. Change the appropriate file permissions save the Magmi profile again, you are done!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you hit `Save Profile` after selecting the CSV file in the dropdown.

As a final check, open the **magmi/conf/Magmi_CSVDataSource.conf** file and see if the `filename` variable is set to the correct CSV location:

```
[Magmi_CSVDataSource]
CSV:importmode = "local"
CSV:basedir = "var/import"
CSV:filename = "/absolute/server/path/to/your/import.csv"
CSV:remoteurl = 
CSV:remoteuser = 
CSV:remotepass = 
CSV:separator = ","
CSV:enclosure = ":DQUOTE:"
CSV:headerline =
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if "Filesystem Path to magento directory" is correct? The default value is:

```
"../.."
```

This is correct when Magmi is installed in:

```
[magento_root]/magmi/web/magmi.php
```

I think you can also enter the absolute path to you Magento directory.